# Does Asus router require internet on initial setup?

Tags: networking, router, security

I am setting up a fresh ASUS router. The instructions are

connect the computer to the router and the router to the modem
power everything on
enter router.asus.com in browser to enter ASUS's Web GUI.
I know this router needs several updates as it has been sitting in its box for over a year. I would prefer not connecting it to the internet before I update the firmware and admin password.

I have tried manual ip, and other configs to enter the Web GUI without connecting to the internet.

Does ASUS router require internet connection to enter the router's Web GUI? Is there any other method?

Comment: No, you should be able to connect a local PC to the router, and access its configuration pages.  Use a wired connection to one of the LAN ports.  "*I have tried manual ip*" -- Using a static IP address on the PC would require that you know the subnet that the router is using.

Comment: Usually router.asus.com would be resolved by the routers internal DNS to the routers IP address. If that is not working, check for the gateway IP with `ipconfig /a` and enter that into your browser. It is also possible that the routers default IP is printed on its "nameplate" on the bottom

Answer (score 1):

For all current Asus routers (regardless if they run the stock Asus firmware or the AsusWrt alternative) you can connect to it without any internet connection.
This goes for both the initial setup as any later configuration.
(But you do need a computer with a wired network connection. Wifi only won't work for the initial config as Wifi won't  be setup yet.)

Simply set your computer to DHCP and connected it (wired) to one of the LAN ports on the router.
The PC will be provided an ip-address by the router and you connect to the routers web-interface by pointing your web-browser to http://router.asus.com
(The router will automatically point router.asus.com to its own internal ip-address if it can't connect to an internet DNS server.)

Or you check the default gateway your PC received from DHCP as this is actually your own router and simply connect to that address with the web-browser.